# loop for selecting consequtive rolling rows of matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

i am beginner in MATLAB. I need to create a loop that will select a number of rolling consequtive rows from a matrix and produce a new matrix that will display elements of selected rows in columns. For instance:

a =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
```

loop = 2 ,meaning to select a rolling of 2 consequtive rows, row 1&2 row 2&3 row 3&4,)

the expected result would be the following matrix:
b =

```
 1     4     7
 2     5     8
 3     6     9
 4     7    10
 5     8    11
 6     9    12
```

elements of selected rows should be placed in the new matric in columns.

Anyway I can do this?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how general you want to make it.  You have a lot of unspoken assumptions in your question and "rolling" is an ambiguous term.  For your specific case, for input matrix A, "loop" = n:

```
function B = rollup(A,n)
B = [];
for i = 1:n
   Btemp = transpose(A(i:i+2,:));
   B = [B;Btemp];
end
```

Note that this will only work with your very specific case where you have three columns, and you can't have n > l-2  where l is the number of rows.